# remove anything after this string END_PAGEREFS and remove anything before BEGIN_PAGEREFS

Tags: notepad

i have large numbers of text files and i am in problem that i want to remove anything after this string END_PAGEREFS and remove anything before BEGIN_PAGEREFS as i want in between them.

using notepadd ++  or frontpage 2003  or powergrip software regular-expressions.info

help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In notepad++, try opening some files, and replacing

```
BEGIN_PAGEREFS.*
```

and

```
END_PAGEREFS.*
```

marking the "Regular Expression" and "Replace in all opened files" options.