# notepad++ : keep anything between 2 keywords recursively?

Tags: regex, notepad++

How to keep any text between 2 keywords and remove the other parts recursively ?

note: the beginning of a line is starting with a Keyword.

Example :

```
some text
Keyword1
      More text
Keyword2
some text
Keyword1
      More text
Keyword2
some text
(note : the sequence Keyword1/More text/Keyword2 is repeated more than 200 times)
some text
Keyword1
      More text
Keyword2
some text
```

Result :

```
Keyword1
      More text
Keyword2
Keyword1
      More text
Keyword2
(note : the sequence Keyword1/More text/Keyword2 is repeated more than 200 times)
Keyword1
      More text
Keyword2
```

I have found here [remove anything after this string END_PAGEREFS and remove anything before BEGIN_PAGEREFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11054220/remove-anything-after-this-string-end-pagerefs-and-remove-anything-before-begin) that I need to add ".*" after the keywords. But it doesn't work. ;(

note: I have done this: replace "Keyword1.*" "*" with "Keyword2.*"
and I have checked : "Wrap around" and "regular expression"
I have also checked with Find + Count if I had chosen correct keywords. They seems correct to me.

Here are some pictures of what I have tried :
Before :
[image: Before]

After hitting "Replace all" :

[image: After]

Thanks in advance ;)
Edit : I have updated my example as I have in fact more than 200 sequences for keyword1/more text/keyword2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do, is check '. matches newline' and then enter the following:

```
Find what: Keyword2.*?Keyword1

Replace with:Keyword2\nKeyword1
```

That way, you're replacing everything between the two keywords with nothing.
That just leaves you to find everything up to the first `Keyword1` and everything after the last `Keyword2`.

Comment: It won't delete if there any unwanted text before first Keyword 1 at the top and after last Keyword2 at the bottom

Comment: @Amit That's correct, and I've admitted that in my answer. It depends on the body of text. If it's littered with keywords, this takes care of most, except the first and the last. Those should be doable by hand.
IT's the 90-10 rule at work. You can spend 10% of your time to fix 90% of the issue, and spend 90% of your time to fix the remaining 10%, or you can just do the 90% and do the rest by hand, which would be quicker. We're talking about Notepad++ here, not some automated process that has to run without supervision.

Comment: @SQB thanks for your help. I appreciated. ;) This works if I have only 2 sequences Keyword1/more text/keyword2. But in fact I have more than 200 sequences. Sorry for my error of not being more explicit at first. So I am updating my question. Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: @Erb Please note the `?` after the `*`, making it capture reluctantly (as little as possible).

Comment: @SQB Wow! Many thanks. ;) I had haven't seen the "?" ! This is working like a charm! ;) Many many thanks again. ;)